# Cycle thru database and delete records with duplicate info

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have imported data into my database and there are a crap ton of records (about 1.7 mil) however there are a bunch with duplicate information and wondering the best way to go thru and delete all the records with the same information.

The table contains two rows with reference_ids that i want to check.  It has a food_id and compound_id.  I want to cycle thru and delete all duplicates where both food_id and compound_id are the same as another record.  I tried doing this:

```
def self.delete_dup
        @contents = Content.select('DISTINCT ON (food_id, compound_id) *').pluck(:id)
        @duplicates = Content.where.not(id: @contents).delete_all

    end
```

But it throws an error cause there are too many parameters in the @contents to put in the where

Comment: Do your delete in batches.

Comment: How would I do that, I can't batch the content ids cause it would delete stuff I didn't include in the batch and don't want that

Answer (score 0):

It might look something like:

```
def self.delete_dup
  Content.select('DISTINCT ON (food_id, compound_id) *').pluck(:id).tap do |good_ids|
    (Content.pluck(:id) - good_ids).each_slice(1000) do |batch|
      Content.where(id: batch).delete_all
    end
  end
end
```

**NOT TESTED!** It may be inefficient, but if you're only doing this once, you may not care. Naturally, you may need to fiddle with your `each_slice` size  - you'll want it to be as big as possible without making AR barf.

Comment: Just realized I can separate it into individual food_ids and cycle thru all the foods one by one and delete the duplicates for each food instead of trying to do everything at once